# Minimum width for view when label is controlling width

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I’ve been trying to do the following for quite some time without success.. I’m super grateful for any advice or tips.

Imagine having a `UIView` that has a fixed height and that’s horizontal/vertical in whatever superview it’s implemented in. Imagine that the view has a `UILabel` that controls its width.

How can you now set a minimum width for that `UIView`? Just in case the `UILabel` is empty or has a 2 character string, I’d like the `UIView` to have at least 50 pix width.

Here's a visual example:

[image: Visual example]

Imagine the UILabel having no text. Then the UIView would have 0 width. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: label is within UiView ?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a width constraint with the minimum required width for the `UIView` and change the relation from **Equal** to **Greater Than or Equal**.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make the UIView.width = UILabel.width constraint priority less than 1000.

Add a UIView.width >= 50 constraint priority 1000.